# Message box in bottom-left

Tags: html, css, popup

I've only recently really gotten into trying to learn how to do web-development, and the reason I actually got into it, was because I was incredibly curious on how to make this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz1BR.jpg.
Not the chat, but in the bottom-left, you can see what I'm looking at. I'd really like to make something similar, with a drop-shadow. Currently, this is what I got:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

}
<style>
.rectangle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #FFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
}
.rectangle {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 53px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
}
.rectangle class = "full-height"
#rectangle {

}
</style>
<style>
.text {
color: #151515;
text-align: left;
width: 300px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-left: 6%;


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="text"> </div>
 <div class="text"><span class="text"> <h2 style="font-size:21px"> This is a test text! This text is quite fine. I have no idea what I'm doing.  <h2> </span>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Okay, so, you can most likely tell I have no clue what I'm doing. I've really been enjoying working on this, but I still have no clue really how to do a lot of things. Here are a few of those things:

- How do I make a box like this always appear responsively to the size of the screen?
- How do I 'parent' the text to the box, so that the text scales according to the box, and not independently? I don't know how to better describe it.
- Would there be a more effective way of going about this (or have there been made any github depositories that already made this, so I could take a look at that code)?

To any of you who see this, thank you so much for reading. I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative positioning for sizing the box according to the screen

OR

You can use 'Responsive Media Queries'(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

---

For scaling text according to the popup, you may use the 'rem' unit is CSS. What it basically does is it scales your text according to the size of the parent.

Check this link: (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-size/)

---

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Before diving into CSS, first structure your HTML appropriately. You ask about parenting items and that's done with wrapping things with opening/closing tags:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="message_container">
  <div id="message_content">message</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

With your HTML proper, then you work on styling:

```
#message_container {

  /* to position it at bottom-left (dependent on the parent) */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 2em;

  /* to position the contents within the box (ie the message text) */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  /* to style the message box in particular ways */
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

**Responsive optimization:**

Once your structure (HTML) and style (CSS) are solid, then you can think about responsiveness. To do this, you'd want to be exploring CSS @media rules to change the box style properties according to some conditions (e.g. screen width). Its all subjective, so you have to trial-and-error yourself to clean up the layout at different screen sizes.

For example:

```
/* for screens smaller than 320px width */
@media (max-width: 320px) {

  /* make the message slimmer, and center it */
  #message_container {
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
  }

  /* make the message text smaller */
    #message_content {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}
```

**Controlling the box:**

If you want this box to appear-and-disappear according to different events (like 2 seconds after the page fully loads, or when the user clicks something elsewhere), then you'll be looking at using Javascript. There's plenty of tutorials for that.

This is the general process.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/GzVQgK)

```css
#message_container {

  /* to position it at bottom-left (dependent on the parent) */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  left: 2em;

  /* to position the contents within the box (ie the message text) */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* to style the message box in particular ways */
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  
  #message_container {
    padding: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
  }
  
    #message_content {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="message_container">
  <div id="message_content">message</div>
</div>
```